# To analyze the performance of class/method available in project by Jprofiler

Tags: jprofiler

I am using Jprofiler 10.0 with intelliJ Ideaa 15.x. I have done all the setting regarding to integrate the jprofiler with intelliJ and it is successfully done.

I am able to see all the in-build Java classes and packages in jprofiler client UI but unable to find the classes or package which is written by me.

How can I include my own classes and exclude all the in-build Java classes? I need to analyze the performance only for those classes which is available in my project or application.

Comment: Are you looking at the call tree? If you open the session settings and activate the filter settings tab, you can delete the default exclusive filters and add inclusive filters for your top-level packages.

Comment: Thanks Ingo, much appreciated. 

I am looking the java classes or package which is written by me which will be going to use for profiling.

What are the top level packages, needs to be included. Please let me know.

Inclusive filer mean profiled right because Inclusive filer name is not available in Jprofiler 10.0

Comment: So if all youe classes are below the `com.mycorp` package, add `com.mycorp` as a profiled classes filter.

Comment: I am not able to find out my package name under add profiled package option. It is showing all other packages like sun, javassist, org etc. but its not showing my package com.mycorp.

Comment: For launched sessions, the package browser it will show classes that are on the configured classpath. You should enter them manually in your case. Also, you can check the "All objects" view to see if you are actually profiling the correct VM. It will show you all classes that have been instantiated, regardless of call tree filters.

Comment: when I run it through profiler button from IntelliJ then it triggered the Jprofiler window but when I run through attach to jvm button then it triggered Jprofiler window with no JVM (process name) displaying. 

When I click on activate IDE button on jprofiler then it doesn't navigate to IntelliJ. 

Could you please help me to find out the solution of both issue?

Below is the details of version using:-
1) IntelliJ : 15.x
2) JProfiler : 10.0.3
3) Java 1.8

Comment: I don't understand your problem and this is not a good format to discuss several unrelated issues. Please send a detailed description of the issue to support@ej-technologies.com